# using django tags with javascript function during hyperlinking

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I have a html code snippet

```
<a href = "{% url home %}?p=1">home</a>
```

I want to add a call to javascript funciton in the end of url, 
if home url is http://localhost/home then above code generates

```
http://localhost/home?p=1
```

however I do not understand how to add a parameter at the end of it.
following does not work

```
<a href = "{% url home %}?p=1"+getParameters()>home</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not using template tags properly (see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#url)

Correct:

```
{% url <url-name> %}
```

Now "{{ url home }}" returns empty string so you're adding GET param for current URL.

{{ x }} form returns variable named "x".

#### Adding parameters to URL using JS

This is simple example of on click script changing anchor url:

```
<a href="{% url home %}?p=1" onclick="return getParameters(this);">anchor</a>
<script>
function getParameters(elem) {
    elem.href = elem.href + "&abc=1";
}
</script>
```

Comment: You cannot add JS function results to URL like that. If you want to add parameters to URL do it in onClick.

Comment: then how will I do this, i.e., adding parameters to onclick element on the fly